# R Shiny - create a table and populate it with the data frame data selected in drop down menu

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, dropdown, datalist

I am continuing my struggles through R & R Shiny and have a question. I have a list of data frames. I want to use the names of the data frames from this list, to populate selectInput, and based on the selection of the data frame, I want to be able to view selected data frame, and see the statistics of its columns.
So far I have found this code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    reactive_df <- reactive({
      if(input$x=="All")
        return df
      else
        return(select(df, starts_with(input$x)))
    }

    output$x <- renderDataTable(reactive_df())

}
```

But it does not do exactly what I want. Does anyone know how to create the table and the summaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-app.html#adding-ui):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", choices = ls("package:datasets")),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
    summary(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
    dataset
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

If you have your own list of dataset, you can use `[[...]]` instead of `get`:

```
datasetlist <- list(iris = iris, mtcars = mtcars)
data <- datasetlist[[input$datasetname]]
```

for example if `input$datasetname=='iris'`, you can check that this will assign `iris` to `data` for further processing:

```
data <- datasetlist[["iris"]]
data
```

Another option is :

```
data <- eval(parse(text=input$datasetname))
```

Comment: Hi Waldi thank you so much. I have my own list of data frames, and I want to call them like this: names(list). I did not want to specify each of the data frame nested there if it is unnecessary

Comment: If you already have a list, this is perfect, `choices=names(mylist)` in `selectInput` and then you get the data for displaying by  `mylist[[input$dataset]]`